# @media query css doesn't works

Tags: html, css, web-applications, media-queries

I'm working on a webapp like spotify for personal purpose, I'm having some truble with the @media query, it just don't works.

This is the css code:

```
/* Screen Adapting */
@media (height <= 730px) {
    .txt-large { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;}
    .txt-small { font-size: 11px; }
    .txt-detail { font-size: 8px; color: #8E8E8E; }

    i.fa {
        font-size: 2px;
    }

    i.fa-plus {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

}
```

while this is the html:

```
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-menu">
            <div id="user">
                <div id="user-icon"></div>
                <div id="user-info">
                    <div id="user-name" class="txt-small">Michele Marchisella</div>
                    <div id="user-membership" class="txt-detail">Registered User</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="home" class="active">
                <i class="fa fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                <h3 class="txt-large">Home</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="coming-soon">
                <i class="fa fa-solid fa-question"></i>
                <h3 class="txt-large">Coming Soon</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar-library">
            <div id="library-header">
                <div id="library-header-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>
                    <h3 class="txt-large">Library</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="hover">
                    <i class="fa fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tryed changing the query like this, and this seems to work, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in the other way:

```
/* Screen Adapting */
@media (min-height: 730px) {
    .txt-large { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;}
    .txt-small { font-size: 11px; }
    .txt-detail { font-size: 8px; color: #8E8E8E; }

    i.fa {
        font-size: 2px;
    }

    i.fa-plus {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

}
```

Comment: `@media screen and (max-height: 730px) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first way isn't fully supported yet. Here's the format for media queries you can use for now.

```
@media (max-height: 730px) {
  /* … */
}
```

We use `max-height` because we only want to target all heights below and up to the maximum height (i.e. <=). If we change it to `min-height`, then we target all heights at and above the minimum height (i.e. >=).

This should help you with all you need to know about CSS Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Mhh I see, but I viewed some yt shorts/video online that uses this syntax: @media (height <= 730px), even in the link you posted there is a reference of this syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#syntax_improvements_in_level_4

Comment: @JustKali Depends on [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#browser_compatibility). The new syntax you're trying to use (Media Queries Level 4) isn't fully supported yet. Would advise using the conventional syntax for now or incorporating a tool like [PostCSS](https://postcss.org)

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped me. (Tryed to upvote but I need 15 rep, I'm sorry)